# How do I make objects collide with text?

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I'm a beginner in Blender, and I'm making an animation where an animated piece of text collides with balls in its path, causing them to roll.  I was just wondering if there was some way to tackle this with some kind of physics simulation.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your text to a mesh as indicated in the image below to get more options in the physics panel.

[image]